# Clicking a row that is partly visible in Silverlight grid

Tags: c#, silverlight, grid

I have a problem while trying to select a row that is partly visible in Telerik Grid using Telerik test framework.

Below is the code snippet:

```
Find<FrameworkElement>(Reference).User.Click();
```

Below is the grid. The highlighted arrow is the partly visible row:
[image]
Where reference is the locator of the grid which is found by inspecting the Grid row through Silverlight Spy.

The clicking of row fails only when the row is partly visible and works fine when the row is fully visible. Partly visible case could be a situation where only few pixels of a row is visible. Here the element is successfully found/located ; but clicking fails. Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Does your test framework have some `ScrollIntoView` utility method?  `Find<FrameworkElement>(Reference).ScrollIntoView();`

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't support ScrollIntoView(). Though there is a SetToVisible() option it doesn't seem to perform anything.

Comment: If your test framework offers some kind of `Scroll()` method you could try to implement such a utility method yourself.